# Python Random Number Diffrent

Tags: python, random

Hi guys I'm a beginner python developer. I want to randomly generate a number between 0 and 20. The user needs to guess what the number is. If the user guesses wrong, tell them their guess is either too **high or too low.** I made almost everything, but I didn't made this section. >if the user guesses wrong, tell them their guess is either too high or too low.

This is the code

```
import random

guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
random.randint = [
    (1,2,3,4,5),
    (6,7,8,9,10),
    (11,12,13,14,15),
    (16,17,18,19,20)
]
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    guess_count += 1

    if guess < random.randint:
        print("Low guess")
    elif guess > random.randint:
        print("High guess")
    elif guess == random.randint:
        print("You won!")
        break
else:
    print("You failed!")
```

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Several problems here:  (1) `random.randint` is a function.  To call it you need to add parentheses, i.e. `random.randint()`.  But you also need to pass arguments to it.  And you need to *save the result*.  Otherwise it will change every time.  Call it once, before entering the loop.  Assign the result to a variable.    Use the variable in the loop. Also, the question needs more focus.  You should complete the program, then if there's a specific bug, ask about the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is specifically here:

```py
random.randint = [
    (1,2,3,4,5),
    (6,7,8,9,10),
    (11,12,13,14,15),
    (16,17,18,19,20)
]
```

You need to read a bit on [Python modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and how they work. What you intended on doing was:

```py
import random

guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
random_int = random.randint(1, 20)

print(random_int)
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    guess_count += 1

    if guess < random_int:
        print("Low guess")
    elif guess > random_int:
        print("High guess")
    elif guess == random_int:
        print("You won!")
        break
else:
    print("You failed!")
```

Comment: You made random_int = random.randint(1, 20) okey, i am understand.